# Google app engine Flexible env how to download the logs

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to download my `Google App Engine` `Flexible Environment` `Logs` to my `Local Machine`. I saw this link [downloading-logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/downloading-logs) for `Standard` env but I didn't find any relevant information about the Flexible env.

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not currently possible to download locally the logs from a flex environment GAE app in a similar manner as the one you referenced for a standard environment GAE app. Most likely because of the different format and the lack of an API for programatically reading them.

From [Logging](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#logging):

> Like the standard environment, logging works automatically in the
>   flexible environment. However, the logs are collected in a different
>   format. Logs will not be bundled by requests and logs from `stdout`
>   and `stderr` are collected separately.
>
> If you want more control over application logging, the ability to
>   group logs, and the ability to log additional metadata, you can use
>   the [Stackdriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) API directly with the [Google Cloud
>   client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/cloud-client-libraries).
>
> For more details, see the following guide:
>
> - [Writing Application Logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs)

And from [Reading logs via API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs#reading_logs_via_api):

> There is no API for reading App Engine logs created in the flexible
>   environment.

One alternative I can think of would be to export your logs to Cloud Storage and download them from there (YMMV, I didn't actually do that). From [Writing Application Logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-application-logs):

> The request and application logs for your app are collected by a
>   [Stackdriver Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent). See [Quota Policy](https://cloud.google.com/logging/quota-policy) for the logs
>   retention policy and for the maximum size of log entries. If you want
>   to store your logs for a longer period, you can [export your logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export)
>   to Cloud Storage. You can also export your logs to BigQuery and
>   Pub/Sub for further processing.